How to get position of point using Points of Curve?
I was searching for a node setup for this question: Move an object along a curve via an axis in geometry nodes, and have found strange behavior, that can't understand. For me, it looks like a bug, but I want to make sure that I haven't missed something.
So I started as a basic setup, that puts an instance in the lowest position of the curve. I thought that it is easy to get point using points of curve node with sorting by Z-position. It should work quite well if the curve is subdivided enough.

But instead of getting position of the lowest point in the curve, it gets position of the first point:

Even the index is correct:

So I tried to sample index first using sample index node, and to my surprise, this works:

For me, it looks very strange and dirty workaround. What is going on here?
Here is the file if you want to test:


Good news: This is definitely not a bug.
In your first example, the position of an object is set with Set Position. In doing so, a value is queried via Sample Index based on the instance domain. However, this node gets its values from a different domain, which means that the resulting value is always 0.
In your second example, however, you query the position via another Sample Index node, which previously queries the correct index in the point domain. Therefore, the second Sample Index node receives the position of the point with the lowest Z-value, which was determined by the previous sorting by Points of Curve. The additional selection of the index is also unnecessary in this case, because it is the same for all points here.
However, to solve the task efficiently, I would recommend the following setup:

Here I simply sort the elements beforehand so that the point with index 0 is always the one with the lowest Z-position. This makes it easier to determine and process this value from a different domain, for example, if you only have a single instance.

And yes, if you want to use the Points of Curve node, then you would actually have to do this in a similar way to how you have already shown it:

You use Sample Index to get the position of the point that corresponds to the index with the lowest Z value.

Get a single position from the original curve
Get a single integer value at the given index
Get the integer value from the curve at index 0 (which is the one with the lowest Z position)

The difference here is that, rather than with fields, which seems strange, only a single value is ever transferred.

But how to use Points of Curve correctly in this case?
